# Let $f(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$ and $a \in \Bbb R$. Show that $(x-a)^2 \mid f(x) \iff f(a)=0$ and $f'(a)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

> Let $f(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$ and $a \in \Bbb R$. Show that $(x-a)^2 \mid f(x) \iff f(a)=0$ and $f'(a)=0$.

The first implication follows from the product rule. If $(x-a)^2 \mid f(x)$, then $f(x)=(x-a)^2Q(x)$ for some $Q \in \Bbb R[x]$. Now $f(a)=0$ and $f'(x)=2(x-a)Q(x)+(x-a)^2Q'(x)$ and so $f'(a)=0+0=0$.

I don't know how to prove the converse. If I assume that $f(a)=0$ and $f'(a)=0$, then from the first equality I can derive that $(x-a)\mid f(x)$ and from the latter that $(x-a) \mid f'(x)$.

I also can derive that $f(x)=(x-a)P(x)$ for some $P \in \Bbb R[x]$ and that $f'(x)=P(x)+(x-a)P'(x)$, but I don't know how to conclude that the square of $(x-a)$ divides $f$?

Comment: I'd try do it the other way  we have $f'(x) = (x-a)Q(x)$ and try to figure out what the antiderivative is.

Comment: Hint: change the basis $f(x)=c_0+c_1(x-a)+c_2(x-a)^2+\cdots+c_n(x-a)^n$ then $f(a)=f'(a)=0\implies c_0=c_1=0$ and it is immediate that you can factor $(x-a)^2$.

Comment: You can consider that $\frac {P(x)}{(x-a)^2} = Q(x) + \frac {R(x)}{(x-a)^2}$ for some $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ of degree at most $1$.  As $(x-a)|P(x)$ we must have $(x-a)|R(x)$ and as $R(x)$ is degree at most $1$, $R(x) =cx+ca$ for some $c\in \mathbb R$.  So $P(x) = (x-a)^2Q(x) + cx + ca$. Take the derivative of that.  Then if $(x-a)|P'(x)$ it follows that $c= 0$.

Comment: .... take zwim's comment which is oodles shorter and clearer than mine....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, so you have:
$$f'(x) = P(x)+(x-a)P'(x)$$
Let $x = a$. Then:
$$0 = f'(a) =P(a) + 0 =P(a)$$
Since $P$ is a polynomial, it follows that $P(x) = (x-a)Q(x)$. But this means that:
$$f(x) = (x-a)^2 Q(x)$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(a) = 0$. Then $(x-a)|f$. Then $f = (x-a)g$ and by the product rule $f' = g + (x-a)g'$. Now if $(x-a)|f'$ this does immediately imply that $(x-a)|g$.

Not much harder to prove:
$f$ has a root of order at least $n$ in $a$ exactly if all $f, f', f^{(2)}, \ldots, f^{(n-1)}$ vanish in $a$, with the order is exactly $n$ if $f^{(n)}(a)\neq 0$.

This forms the basis for checking if a polynomial has multiple roots (note that this check can be performed in the field the polynomial is defined on, while the root might live in some algebraic extension of it).